# How do you define a scalar-valued UDF?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm reading Microsoft's 70-433 SQL Training Kit, and I've come up against an example where they define the following as a "scalar UDF":

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetCustomerAccountNumber(@CustomerID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ISNULL(
        (
        SELECT
            AccountNumber
        FROM Sales.Customer
        WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
    ), 'NOT FOUND');
END
GO
```

I understand that a scalar UDF (as oppposed to a table-valued one) is one that returns a single value, but it seems to me that the above function will only return a single value if there is only one row returned by the SELECT statement - which will depend on the contents of the table. But I'm happy to assume that there will be only one row returned (what would happen if there wasn't?). But...

They then give an alternative version, which instead of calling the above UDF, does the following:

```
SELECT 
    soh.SalesOrderID
    , soh.OrderDate
    , ISNULL(
        (
        SELECT
            AccountNumber
        FROM Sales.Customer
        WHERE CustomerID = soh.CustomerID
    ), 'NOT FOUND')
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh;
```

They contrast this second example by saying "The use of inline table-valued UDFs does not incur the same performance penalty as the use of scalar UDFs because..."

So, this second example, even though the code is identical to the first, is a table-valued UDF rather than a scalar one? Is this an error in the text, or am I misunderstanding the distinction between a scalar UDF and a table-valued one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference.  Look at the where clause in the first

```
   WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
```

Is matching `CustomerID` against a single integer value (which is a parameter.)

In the 2nd where clause

```
   WHERE CustomerID = soh.CustomerID
```

Is matching against every value of `CustomerID` in the `Sales.SalesOrderHeader` table.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's quite subtle, as the bit I missed out is the call to the scalar UDF, which looks like this:

    SELECT
        soh.SalesOrderID
        , soh.OrderDate
        , dbo.fnGetCustomerAccountNumber(soh.CustomerID) 
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh;

...which calls the UDF for every value of soh.CustomerID... but of course as far as the UDF is concerned it is only being called once, whereas in the second example it is repeating itself for every value of soh.CustomerID... hence being table-valued.

Thankyou.

Comment: (apologies for failing to format this second code chunk in a readable way. It looks fine until I press Enter, at which point it all goes to hell in a handcart. Any advice on how to better-format code chunks gratefully received)

Comment: Sadly you can't format code in comments.  you can put them in the backwards quote ` to get them to be `unformated` as code.